# Linearization of operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $K:X\to Y$ is nonlinear operator between two Banach spaces. That is $f\mapsto K(f)$. The linearized operator is written as $$Kf_0 + K'f_0(f-f_0)$$ I would like to ask is it correct to say that $K'$ is a Frechet derivative? Frechet derivative is a linear operator, right? What does $K'f_0(f-f_0)$ mean? Is it a product of $K'(f_0)$ and $f-f_0$ or it is an operator $K'$ of $f_0(f-f_0)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $K'$ exists at $f_0$, then indeed $K'$ is the Frechet derivative. We can consider $K'$ as a map
$$ K': V \rightarrow B(V,W),$$
where $B(V,W)$ is the space of bounded linear operators from $V$ to $W$. Thus $K'(f_0)$ is an element of $B(V,W)$, so it acts on $(f - f_0)$ as suggested by the expression you wrote out. One should *avoid* calling this a "product", since it's really an operator acting on a vector.

Comment: Thank you! If I consider a simple example. Let $Kf = \int G(f(x))dx$, where $G$ is some continuous function. Then $K'f = \int f(x)G'(f(x))dx$? How can I write $K'f_0(f-f_0)$?

Comment: Forgot to mention that $G$ is nonlinear.

Comment: Would it be $K'f_0(f-f_0) = \int (f(x)-f_0(x))G'(f(x)-f_0(x))dx$?

Comment: I'm actually not exactly sure about your example. What type of object is $Kf$?

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong: You are wrong. In order that $K'$ is a Frechet derivative, you need an additional property.

Comment: That property is implicit in the existence of the linearization, typically. Otherwise the linearization would have unbounded error in a neighborhood of the point.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong: But there are many ways of "linearize" (Frechet, Gateaux, Hadamard,...). E.g. obtaining the Gateaux-derivative by directional derivatives. This is _also_ a linearization.

Comment: @gerw, I suppose I agree, there are some technical delicacies. I think that for this problem though, the notation indicates that $K'f_0$ is to be taken as a linear operator.

Answer (score 4):

As other mentioned, $K'$ maps the points of $V$ to a bounded, linear operator $V \to W$.

In order that you have a Frechet derivative in $f_0 \in V$, you need to verify
$$\lim_{\lVert h\rVert_V \to 0} \frac{\lVert K(f_0 + h) - K(f_0) - K'(f_0)\,h\rVert_W}{\lVert h\rVert_V} = 0.$$

Now, let me answer the question you asked in a comment: Let $G : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and not affine. Let $V = L^p(\mu)$, $W = \mathbb{R}$.
Then, $K = \int G(f(x)) \, d\mu(x)$ is only Frechet differentiable if $p > 1$.
In any case, you need also some additional conditions on $G$, see Goldberg, Kampowski, Tröltzsch: On Nemytskii operators in Lp-spaces of abstract functions,
Math. Nachrichten 155 (1992), 127-140.

**edit:** If $K$ is differentiable (Gateaux or Frechet), you get the derivative
$$K'(f_0) \, h = \int G'(f_0(x)) \, h(x) \, d\mu(x),$$
as expected.

Note that Gateaux differentiability may also hold for $p = 1$.

Comment: Thank you all for answers. I will upvote your posts once my reputation will be high enough and I will be able to do that. @gerw Suppose that conditions on $G$ are satisfied. How would $K'f_0(f-f_0)$ look like? I'm having problems with very basic undertanding.

Comment: @Bayes: I will add that to my answer.

Comment: @gerw Please will you upload that paper you cited. It is not available here.

Answer (score 1):

$K'(f_0)$ is a linear transformation.  So we are talking about a linear operator operating on a vector here.

Comment: So this is like $[K'(f_0)](f-f_0)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.